# Convert a NLTK tree into a array of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, tree, nltk

I would like to convert the following nltk Tree into a array of dictionaries:

```
(S
  I/PRP
  'll/MD
  have/VB
  (amount 1/CD)
  (meal pizza/NN)
  with/IN
  (ingredient bacon/NN)
  and/CC
  (amount 2/CD)
  (meal hamburgers/NNS)
  with/IN
  (ingredient cheese/NN))

[{'amount': '1', 'meal': 'pizza', 'ingredient': 'bacon'},
{'amount': '2', 'meal': 'hamburgers', 'ingredient': 'cheese'}]
```

I have created next code to get it:

```
comanda = [('I', 'PRP'), ("'ll", 'MD'), ('have', 'VB'), ('1', 'CD'), ('pizza', 'NN'), ('with', 'IN'), ('bacon', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('2', 'CD'), ('hamburgers', 'NNS'), ('with', 'IN'), ('cheese', 'NN')]

def IOB_pedido(menu):

    grammar = r"""
        meal:      {<NN|NNS><IN|NN>}       
                     }<IN>{                  
        ingredient: {<IN>?<NN|NNS>}
                     }<IN>{
        amount:    {<CD>}                 
                     {<DT>}
    """
    result = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar).parse(menu)
    iob_tags = tree2conlltags(result)
    tree = conlltags2tree(iob_tags)
    return tree
output = IOB_pedido(comanda)

def tree_to_dict(tree):
    tree_dict = {}
    for nodo in tree:
        if type(nodo) == tuple:
            continue
        salida = []
        key = nodo.label()
        value = nodo[0][0]
        tree_dict.update([(key, value)])
        salida.append((tree_dict))

    return salida

tree_to_dict(output)
```

But for any reason only de second part is shown, which is the reason I don't get next output?

```
[{'amount': '1', 'meal': 'pizza', 'ingredient': 'bacon'},
    {'amount': '2', 'meal': 'hamburgers', 'ingredient': 'cheese'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what I mean is I get as output this:

```
[{'amount': '2', 'meal': 'hamburgers', 'ingredient': 'cheese'}]
```

and I want something like this:

```
[{'amount': '1', 'meal': 'pizza', 'ingredient': 'bacon'},
 {'amount': '2', 'meal': 'hamburgers', 'ingredient': 'cheese'}]
```

I don't know why I get only second part of the tree is included into list of dictionaries.